# A linear, second order, ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For given real numbers $a,b,c$, what would be the best method for solving the ODE,

$$(1-t)x''+a x=0$$

given that $x'(b)=-1$ and $x(b)=c$? Would it make sense trying a substitution to turn this into Bessel's equation? I'm not sure what would work in this instance. Would it make more sense to just use a power series approach?

Comment: by 'substitution' do you mean $(1-t) \to \mu$?

Comment: If that helps. Or something else that makes this look more obviously like Bessel's equation. I'm not really certain.

Comment: I'll give it a go when I can, power series is the go-to method for these types though. I'm not a fan either but it is the simplest technique

Comment: In this case it might be easier to let $s=\sqrt{a(t-1)}$ and then to look for solutions like $x(t)=sy(s)$. You will probably find that $y$ is a Bessel function.

Comment: @mickep, is there a reason why you think this might work? Or is seeing this just a matter of experience?

Comment: I've seen something similar before. I added an answer with some calculations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave it for you to consider different cases. Below, I assume that $t>1$. Let
$$
s=\sqrt{a(t-1)}
$$
and write
$$
x(t)=s y(s).
$$
Differentiating,
$$
x'(t)=\bigl(y(s)+sy'(s)\bigr)\frac{ds}{dt}
$$
and
$$
x''(t)=\bigl(2y'(s)+sy''(s)\bigr)\Bigl(\frac{ds}{dt}\Bigr)^2+\bigl(y(s)+sy'(s)\bigr)\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}.
$$
Moreover,
$$
\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{a}{2s},\quad \frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=-\frac{a^2}{4s^3}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
(1-t)x''(t)+a x(t)&=-\frac{s^2}{a}\biggl(\bigl(2y'(s)+sy''(s)\bigr)\Bigl(\frac{a}{2s}\Bigr)^2+\bigl(y(s)+sy'(s)\bigr)\Bigl(-\frac{a^2}{4s^3}\Bigr)\biggr)+asy(s)\\
&=-\frac{as}{4}y''(s)-\frac{a}{4}y'(s)+\bigl(\frac{a}{4s}+as\bigr)y(s),
\end{aligned}
$$
or, after multiplication by $s$ (and factoring $-a/4$ out),
$$
-\frac{a}{4}\Bigl[s^2 y''(s)+sy'(s)-(1+4s^2)y(s)\Bigr]
$$
In fact, it would have been better to write $x(t)=s y(2s)$, but, comparing with [the modified Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1) and their differential equation, we find that
$$
y(s)=C_1 I_1(2s)+C_2 K_1(2s).
$$

Comment: That seems to make sense, and once I work through the solution, the motivation for your choice of $s$ should be clear. I'm actually interested in the solution where $0<t<1$ but I suspect that $s=\sqrt{a(1-t)}$ will work in that instance. I'll give it a shot.